# Why is there a 1 at the top of a QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

There is a 1 at the top of a QtreeWidget. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `1` is the `columncount` [property](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#columnCount-prop), that, by default, assumes that value.

Your question was not very clear.

If you want to modify the label, you can use [setHeaderLabel](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#setHeaderLabel)/[setHeaderLabels](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#setHeaderLabels) functions.

If you want to hide the label, you can use [setHeaderHidden](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#headerHidden-prop) function.

Please, before ask, use the [Qt documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/).

Comment: I came here looking for the same thing this person asking the question was seeking.  There is nothing in the QT documentation describing a header - sure there's that function but unless I look through the 30 or so methods, types, and constants in the documentation and examine EVERY one, nobody is going to know what it is - I tried clicking on the 1 and noticed you can't click on it - it doesn't highlight - but that doesn't tell me anything - One would just assume their program isn't working or they don't know properly how to use a QTreeWidget.  But this answer helped pointing to a method.

Answer (score 0):

By default qt designer puts 1 there, you need to edit it to suit your need from within qt designer or programatically using the docs.

Comment: but edit how???

Answer (score 0):

This wll change the title of qlistwidget:

self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "xyz", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))